# Sick LMS100 small object filters

Tags: ros, sicklms, laser-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am interfacing with a Sick LMS100 laser scanner and I am having problems filtering small objects (such as grass clippings).  Are there any tools built into ROS that I could use to filter these objects out easily?  If not, what would be the best method for filtering the objects out of the scans?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28222/sick-lms100-small-object-filters/) by [rplankenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/1757/rplankenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had some success doing this by using PointCloud Library's built-in functions, namely [Statistical Outlier Removal](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/statistical_outlier.php#statistical-outlier-removal). It really depends where the majority of your points lie. If there's a lot of grass, this won't work as well. If the grass is sparse, this method could definitely improve your performance. [Radial Outlier Removal](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/remove_outliers.php#remove-outliers) might also work.

**EDIT**:

In order to get a ROS `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` to a pcl cloud, use the following code:

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud_in;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::fromROSMsg(cloud_in, *cloud);
```

The `cloud` variable will now contain a pcl cloud that you can use with the PCL built-in functions.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rplankenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/1757/rplankenhorn/) on 2012-02-23**:
This looks like it could work.  How do you suggest I implement it?  I looked at the PCL page for ROS and the functions to convert from an ROS PointCloud to a PCL PointCloud and back are deprecated.  Am I missing something?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-23**:
Use the fuction `pcl::fromROSMsg()`. The docs might be misleading. This function is not deprecated. The fuction `point_cloud::fromMsg()` is, but not `pcl::fromROSMsg()`.

**Comment by [rplankenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/1757/rplankenhorn/) on 2012-02-23**:
Thanks again.  If the fromMsg is deprecated, how do I convert the pcl::PointCloud back to a PointCloud2?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-23**:
pcl::toROSMsg() does the opposite of pcl::fromROSMsg()